# Accessing Azure Subscription info using ASP.NET MVC App by authenticating user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication

I want to create an ASP.NET MVC application that will authenticate to an Azure tenant and get the information about the underlying tenant info such as subscription ID etc. -

This similar thing has been done by another application here - https://overcast.sharegate.com/login

Let me know any article or related info for this requirement.

Comment: Here's one API to do it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list You're basically asking us to google for you and you barely even have a question. Please have a try yourself.

Comment: Yet I need to know the authentication process...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the Azure Subscription details, you can use the following:

[Subscriptions - Get REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/get)
[Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager/). The Azure SDK for .NET consists of the Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager Namespace and the ISubscriptionClient Interface that would let you get information about your subscriptions and tenants.
However, if you're looking to access information across the Microsoft Cloud services and build unified but unique user experiences, check out the following resources about [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview):

[Building ASP.NET MVC apps with Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/aspnet)
[Module: Build ASP.NET MVC web applications with the Microsoft Graph .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msgraph-build-aspnetmvc-apps/)

For implementing the sign-in experience to Microsoft through an ASP.NET MVC solution, take a look at [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp).

Answer (score 0):

As Nick said, you could use [Tenants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list) Rest Api to get the tenants for your account.

Use Azure ad [Implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow) to get your access token with your username. And send the request to `Tenants` with access token as http header. Then you will get all the tenants for your account and the detailed message like `tenantId`, `tenantName`.

[image]